# Is there a memory issue with this code?

Tags: ios, swift

New to Swift and I'm wondering if I have to deal with (potentially) the same issue in this code as I did in Objective-C:

```
var itemB = EditableItem(title: "Item J")
itemB.onReturn = {(value) in
  var s = itemB.title
  println(value)
}
```

The closure has a reference to `itemB` and `itemB` has a reference to the closure. Does this lead to a cyclic reference and hence a memory leak in Swift or is Swift smart enough to make this a `itemB` a weak var inside the closure?

If not, how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

No, itemB inside the closure exist only as long as itemB is set outside.

Example, you can test this in a Playground.

Let pretend we have this Class mapping with your example:

```
Import Foundation
class EditableItem {
  var title = ""
  var onReturn: ((String)->Void)?

  init(title: String) {
    self.title = title
  }

  deinit {
    println("Deinit")
  }
}
```

And now we run code similar to yours:

```
// Using optional so that I can set it do nil = will dealloc
var itemB:EditableItem? = EditableItem(title: "Item J")
itemB!.onReturn = {(value) in
  var s = itemB!.title
  println(value)
}

// Execute to make sure anything would retain
itemB!.onReturn!("data")
// var is set to nil, same variable inside the closure
itemB = nil // Deinit will run
```

Same example with an variable retaining:

```
var retainer:EditableItem? = nil

var itemB:EditableItem? = EditableItem(title: "Item J")
itemB!.onReturn = {(value) in
  retainer = itemB!
  println(value)
}

// If onReturn() would not be executed, itemB would not be retained
itemB!.onReturn!("data")
// deinit will not be called
itemB = nil
```

And example to make the reference weak:

```
var retainer:EditableItem? = nil

var itemB:EditableItem? = EditableItem(title: "Item J")
// Make sure retainer is weak
itemB!.onReturn = { [weak retainer](value) in
  retainer = itemB!
  println(value)
  // retainer is set here..
}
// retainer is nil here..
itemB!.onReturn!("data")
// retainer is nil here as well..
itemB = nil // And this will deinit
```